# How to download youtube video in current working directory with youtube-dl

Tags: terminal, youtube-dl

How do I download files in the current working directory with youtube-dl?

I want something like `youtube-dl -o pwd "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGHVseYRXDo"` to work.

My config currently looks like:

```
-o ~/Downloads/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s
--format mp4
```

I'd like to retain the file name and format properties, but change the download location to wherever pwd is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `-o filename` is optional, and you don't have to specify the working directory as this is the default one. But if you prefer to specify it, you could use a  command substitution `pwd` or `$(pwd)` so your command could be eg:

```
$ youtube-dl -o "$(pwd)/%(title)s.%(ext)s" url
```

Of course you are free to put any other options like those in your configuration file.

Comment: What do I have to search up to learn the coding language of your answer?

Comment: It's pretty simple and easy, this is coming from a shell command interpreter. You write in a terminal, right ? And you use a command interpreter, like eg bash (`echo $0`), which use the shell language, and provide some other features. `man sh` or `man bash` will give you some infos.